# Draw line with touch and uitextfield above

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to use touch to draw line and while move a uitextfield above the line display the x,y differences between the first and the end

any suggestion to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `touchesBegan:`, `touchesMoved:`, `touchesEnded:` to get the touch points which you can use to display on the text field.

Comment: I need the uitextfield be displayed at the center of the line

Comment: you can get the points from these methods which u can use to calculate its center and then place the textfield on the point

Comment: Once you done with the drawing of line, you can calculate the center coordinate... & give that point to your uitextfield